# How to count the characters of a hexadecimal number

Tags: c

since I'm fairly new to C, so this might be a dumb question.
I aimed to use the bitwise operators & to do bit masking.
For example:
If inputs are 0x00F7 and 0x000F,my program should returns 0x0007. However, the output of 0x007&0x000F is just 7, 0x0077&0x00FF is just 77. So is there any way I can count the characters of a hexadecimal number so that I can know how many zeros should I print out?

```
printf("%X",0x077&0x00FF);
```

Comment: 0x77 and 0x0077 are exactly the same.

Comment: @dbush so why printf has those fancy formating options

Comment: Numbers are just numbers...how many leading zeros to print in the text representation of a number is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to count.
You can get `printf` to pad the number for you, just specify the maximum length like so:

```
printf("%04X", 0x77 & 0xff);
```

Note that when you write an integer (no quotes) it makes no difference if you write 0x0077 or 0x77.

Only when you use `printf` to output a string zeros can be added for visibility.

Comment: Note that the "%X" format expects an unsigned int argument, while the `0x77 & 0xff` value is basically signed.

Comment: @wildplasser true, since the value is small enough to fit in an `int`, but that would not change the printed result. As long as the size of the argument is the same as what the format specifier expects, as far as I know no UB should occur.

Answer (score -1):

```
    unsigned char uc = 0x077&0x00FF;
    unsigned short us = 0x077&0x00FF;
    unsigned int ui = 0x077&0x00FF;
    unsigned long long ull = 0x077&0x00FF;
    
    printf("%0*X\n",sizeof(uc)*2, uc);
    printf("%0*X\n",sizeof(us)*2, uc);
    printf("%0*X\n",sizeof(ui)*2, uc);
    printf("%0*X\n",sizeof(ull)*2, uc);
```

end the output:

```
77
0077
00000077
0000000000000077
```

Comment: Again why DV? It will adapt to the result size itself

Comment: I am not the one who DV you, but why the & calculation inside `sizeof` if you cast it to `unsign short`? Also, why do you assume the OP wants to pad zeros specifically to the size of `unsigned short`?

Comment: @LevM.  because he wants 0x0000 in four digits only 16 bits value will fit . Simple

Comment: My point was that `sizeof` will give the same result for any value you cast to `unsigned short` so this code could be much cleaner and simpler by just writing `sizeof(short)` since unsigned and signed values occupy the same number of bytes. At best you can add the `unsigned` for clarity, but adding the value calculation twice like that just makes the code longer and more confusing.

Comment: @LevM. If you look wider and abstract from the triviality of the example you will see that it is a general abstract solution. But people here have a problem with it.